# How to add notifications to Chat on FirebaseDatabase?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification

When one user send a message to another and save that message in FirebaseDatabase I want the second user to get a notification just like in usual chat app. With Firebase Cloud Messaging API it is not possible as I heard... Please help me :( Maybe with just ideas

Comment: There are a number of different ways this can be done including notifications and observing nodes. What have you tried?

Comment: At the moment I'm just looking for smt to try. Found a bit information that OneSignal can help with this